# Find the interval of definition for the solution of $\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2$, $y(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the interval of definition for the solution of:
$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2$, $y(0) = 0$
I get:  $\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y^2}=dt\Rightarrow\frac{1}{-y} = t + c$
How do I choose the constant of integration, $c$? It seems that simply plugging in $y=0$, $t=0$ won't work because we have $y$ in the denominator, and even if we multiply it over and plug in $y=0$, $t=0$, we get that $1 = 0$, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is $y(t)=0$ for all $t$ (by the uniqueness theorem). Since $y(0)=0$, you can't divide by $y^2$ like you do in your first step.

Comment: It totaly makes sense what you said, but couldn't we say -without looking at the IC -  $$\frac{dy}{y^2}=dt$$ $$-\frac{1}{y}=-\frac{1}{y_0}+t$$ $$y=\frac{y_0}{1-ty_0}$$. So we could conclude that $y_0 = 0$. Hence, $y = 0$? I Mean for the final formula it is totaly irrelevant that $y=0$ is not allowed. I would be happy to hear your perspective on that :).

Comment: You could argue that, when using this general solution for $y(t)$, this constant would be equal to infinity, such that the limit for the expression for $y(t)$ becomes zero.

Comment: @MrYouMath: I prefer to say that the equation is eqivalent to $y=0$ *or* $dy/y^2=dt$, so that you take the exceptional solution into account right away. The fact that your final formula happens to give the right answer also for $y_0=0$ is a bit of a lucky coincidence, since putting $y_0=0$ is the intermediate expressions clearly doesn't make sense. However, it's also clearly not *completely* accidental; maybe one could make up some argument where $y_0 \to 0$ which would justify it, but I find it easier to just argue separately that the formula works in both cases $y_0=0$ and $y_0 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Thank you alot for your explanation :).